# Find the sufficient and necessary condition to make a matrix rational

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose $A^5=2E_n$, where $A$ is a real matrix and $E_n$ is an identity matrix. Please give the sufficient and necessary condition of $n$ such that elements of $A$ are all rational numbers?

I can't figure it out with so few statements.

Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: What is $E_n$? The identity matrix? Or a matrix with a single entry equal to $1$? Presumably you want to use the given identity to draw conclusions about the minimal polynomial of $A$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $A^5=2E_n$ for some rational $A$, then $2^{n/5}=\det(A)$ is rational. Hence $n$ must be divisible by $5$. Conversely, if $n=5m$, since $C^5=2E_5$ when $C$ is the $5\times5$ companion matrix for the polynomial $x^5-2$, we have $(\underbrace{C\oplus\cdots\oplus C}_{m\ \text{ copies}})^5=2E_n$.

Comment: Can you add some details?

Comment: @IntoksLiobein All details have been included. Which part do you not understand?

Comment: Now it is alright. Thank you!